# Populate a row in SQL Server based on a condition (query optimization)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to find all the people who took a timeoff for previous months, I got most of it. But if nobody took a timeoff in the current month, I need to populate a row saying 0 to get my visuals right.

This is what my data looks like:

[image]

This is what I have for the visual:

```
select s.*, DATEPART(MONTH, startd) as timeoff_Mon, 
DATEDIFF(day, startd, endd) as timeoff, getdate() as dat,
DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) as Current_Mon from sample s;
```

[image]

You can see that Jack was the only employee who took time off in January for a day, and John in Feb for 4 days,

Now, in March, I have got the current month which is the last column in the image above from the current date.

Using this current month, is there a way to populate a row or hardcode a row to populate the time off column as 0??

Desired Output:

[image]

Here is the SQL Fiddle with the above-mentioned problem.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e8fbb2ae8dcfec9cc5fdfa784782753

Comment: I think we can use union all but I dont know the syntax, but it has to match the condition that ("If timeoff_mon <> current_mon") then UNION ALL another line.

Comment: Do you *just* want the current month as an extra line? What if it's April and no-one took any time off in March? And how do you want to deal with the situation where people take time off in January last year and its currently January this year?

Comment: You need 1. A monthly calendar table listing every month and it's start and end dates (google "calendar table"); 2. Then learn about outer joins - you just outer join to the calendar table

Comment: Hi @Nick , What happens in the future is not needed. My visual is live information, so for this month, If no one took a time off, I need to hard code an extra row to show time off as 0, I m not sure if (null - null),  ( Which is startd(null) - endd(null)) gives 0.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, Can you share a link where I can get this data?

Comment: I literally highlighted "calendar table" in my comment, right clicked and pressed "search google" and this was the  top result. https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/ . Without being rude: googling is an important skill in IT and you should really start learning

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I searched for this "google calendar table ms sql server", It showed me some other results. I thought It was some new thing that was created by Google for SQL Server :D

Comment: Ah... a miscommunication on my part :) Well hopefully you'll read a few articles and get the concept. Although most articles will describe daily calendar tables, you want a monthly one. This has three columns: MonthLabel (varchar(50), whatever you want to see on your report), MonthStartDate (date), MonthEndDate (date). Then you populate it with a bunch of months, then you outer join to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option is to use `union all` to add the final record if there is no row that overlaps the current month in the table:

```
select 
    s.*, 
    month(startd) as timeoff_mon, 
    datediff(day, startd, endd) as timeoff, 
    getdate() as dat,
    month(getdate()) as current_mon 
from sample s
union all
select null, null, null, null, null, 0, getdate(), datepart(month, getdate())
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from sample s 
    where 
        s.startd < dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0)
        and s.endd >= dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=448ac1c976452121e8e637ba325e8ec3)**:

```
Name       |   ID | STARTD     | ENDD       | timeoff_mon | timeoff | dat                     | current_mon
:--------- | ---: | :--------- | :--------- | ----------: | ------: | :---------------------- | ----------:
Jack       |    5 | 2020-01-25 | 2020-01-26 |           1 |       1 | 2020-03-28 14:28:56.867 |           3
John       |    6 | 2020-02-05 | 2020-02-09 |           2 |       4 | 2020-03-28 14:28:56.867 |           3
null       | null | null       | null       |        null |       0 | 2020-03-28 14:28:56.867 |           3
```

Comment: Hi @GMB, Thanks for the reply, What if there is no record in February, Will it show the blank statement for February as well? I was trying it on DBFiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=117336427fb6e79c5112af0bfc015ccf